# Spring roo - adding CLOB field

Tags: java, sql, spring-roo, clob

In my web application, I am saving some Text message in a COLUMN of a DB table(Oracle). Earlier the VARCHAR2 length(maximum length) is (500 BYTE). Now the maximum length is increased to 4000 characters. So I need to add a 'CLOB' field in my domain class.
Can anyone please clarify what are the steps need to be followed in order to create a CLOB field in my domain class. I also have CLOB cloumn in my DB.
(What is the command/syntax to start with?)

Comment: You could try following the instructions in this [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-roo-save-read-blob-object-spring-roo-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding CLOB at database

and adding the below code in the domain class is the solution.

```
@Lob
private String message;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a `CLOB` field named `message` then you would run the following command on the Roo Shell:

```
field string --fieldName message --lob true
```